# jquery fancybox width issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

The jquery fancybox width is abnormal. means it is equal to the width of the page. If i change the class name to 'iframe' width works fine else width is miss behaving.

```
$(".iframe_reg2").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600,
        'speedOut'      :   200,
        'overlayShow'   :   false,
            'width'         :       400
    });
```

And my Html is

```
 <a class="iframe_reg2" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

Comment: Hey Could you please provide more info? I took your code and did [this](http://pastebin.com/w3Wdnvpq) but all i ended up with , was [this](http://i51.tinypic.com/6hnebl.png)

Comment: When I click the link "Google" contents are displayed in fancybox with 100% width despite of setting width in the initialization code.

Comment: The strange thing is that when i change the class name to "iframe" it opens with a specific width and height. 
I am colliding my head with my chair in anxiety. Please help

Comment: I just added an answer , check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U need to set autoDimensions to false if you're specifying the width yourself. So ideally , the call should be

```
$(".iframe_reg2").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600,
        'speedOut'      :   200,
        'overlayShow'   :   false,
        'autoDimensions':   false,
        'width'         :   400
    });
```

I think this should work :)

Comment: I have no words to thank you buddy. Thank you so much. Yes it worked.

Comment: No problem mate . All the best !

Comment: Does this apply to percentage width and height too?

Answer (score 0):

Your anchor tag does not have an href value, which is a key attribute to making the plugin work. (edit: I see now what the "iframe" class is for, but I like using the query string instead). It's a bit difficult to tell what you mean to do with your sample, but my guess is that you're attempting to grab Google and put it into the fancybox (as a test).

You should also remove the comma from your last attribute, as it will trip up some browsers.

I can't see why this wouldn't work:

```
$(".pageViewer").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'       :   600,
        'speedOut'      :   200,
        'overlayShow'   :   false
    });
```

with HTML

```
<a class="pageViewer" href="http://google.com?iframe">Google</a>
```

Comment: Sorry it was mistyped here. It has href attribut. Please help

Comment: That's already the best answer I can give. ;-) Instead of using a class of 'iframe' I used the query string ('?iframe') method. If it's not working, it could be other generic problems like loading jQuery twice, scripts loading out of order, etc. Only a live example could help anyone debug that part. Your updated code is missing both of those. You need one or the other. Add class "iframe" or add the query string like my example.